Bottom Nav Bar on device doesn't match with XML Preview
Picture Here
As shown here, the bottom navigation bar in the device has some extra space in the bottom. I want to get rid of it. Here is my activity.xml code
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_black"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNav"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:itemIconSize="45dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/orange_500"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

When I set a fixed layout_height in the BottomNavigationView, the correct height reflects in the device however the icons are like absolutely placed so it kind of overflows (put off screen).
I tried setting margin and paddings to 0dp didnt help. I tried using android gravity also didn't help. I appreciate any help :D
UPDATE: Im very certain that it has something to do with the labels or the ripple space.
UPDATE: Apparently it was already solved in other forums I don't know how I didnt come across those. Anyways the solution is this.
your_bottom_nav_id.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(null)
your_bottom_nav_id.setPadding(0,0,0,0)


Please don't add solutions inside the question. Consider posting an actual answer
